# XSLT text output processor differences

Tags: xslt

I encountered some peculiar difference in behavior of XSLT processors. I wonder what is the reason behind this and whether there is a full overview available somewhere of processor differences.
I tested the following simple transformation (with a dummy input):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>1=&#xA;2=&#xD;3=&#xD;&#xA;4=&#xA;&#xD;end</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Run in XML Spy (v 2011 sp1 x64), the output is:

```
1=  
2=  
3=  
4=  

end
```

In all cases, in hex after the `=`, and on the line after `4=`, two characters have been added, `0D` and `0A`.
Apparently, XML Spy replaces each request for `&xA;` or `&xD;` by a full CR+LF occurrence, except when CR and LF are requested in that order, right after each other (see the 3= part).

But when run in saxon9he, I get a warning that I am running a v1.0 stylesheet with a v2.0 processor, and the output is

```
1=  
2=3=  
4=  
end
```

In this case, all requests for `&xA;` are replaced by `0D 0A` (so a CR is added in front of the LF), but a request for `&xD;` outputs the requested CR, not an additional LF.

Rerunning in XML Spy setting XSLT version to 2.0 gives the same result as for 1.0, so I guess it's not a different convention in the two XSLT versions that is causing this.
Most probably, this is just a diff between tools we have to know about, but I wonder whether there is more to say on the subject.

Comment: If you output to file in the style sheet, one expects the second version with single CR resp. LFs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2.0 specification states that with output method text, it is implementation-defined how line endings will be represented (More specifically, "A newline character in the instance of the data model MAY be output using any character sequence that is conventionally used to represent a line ending in the chosen system environment.").

The XSLT 1.0 says nothing (which is not really any different).

Some implementations might use a single newline consistently, some might output exactly what you asked for, some might use the default line ending for the operating system you are running on.

Comment: Michael, I found the doc you were referring to and add it here for reference: [xslt-xquery-serialization](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/)